heredoc not working in Ubuntu 24.04
Upgraded to 24.04 on two servers, and cannot run remote script (heredoc) on second server from first server as I did on 22.04 before. Is this option removed from Ubuntu 24.04?

What shell are you using? Can you provide a minimal testable demonstration of a heredoc not working?

Is there an error message when you run heredoc in the terminal?

I'll post some info tomorrow. Here's night now, on my part of he planet.

No error message. But no version info from this.

#!/bin/bash
function getversion()
{
if
backdock="$(cat <<EOF
who
if
vers=$( cat ~/version.txt )
then
echo "$vers"
exit 0
else
exit 1
fi
logname
EOF
)"
ssh -t username@192.168.1.2 "$backdock"
then
return
else
false
fi
}
getversion

@SigurdAlnæs please use the [edit] button to add that information to your question - formating is especially important in this case since the heredoc structure is sensitive to indentation

The script is executed on 192.168.1.1, so the heredoc is executed on 192.168.1.2. Ok. I'm new here. Code is indented, but indentation was lost on pasting the code here.

Please have a look here, it will explain how to format your post properly; you can't do that in the comments, you should edit your question as steeldriver suggested. I would have edited it into your post myself, however since we're talking about heredocs not working whitespace is cruciat, so please make sure we get to see exactly what you have.

I'm assuming your indentation is some version of this
#!/bin/bash
function getversion() {
    if  backdock="$(cat <<EOF
            who
            if vers=$( cat ~/version.txt )
            then
                echo "$vers"
                exit 0
            else
                exit 1
            fi
            logname
EOF
        )"
        ssh -t username@192.168.1.2 "$backdock"
    then
        return
    else
        false
    fi
}
getversion

It's not right to say "the heredoc is executed on 192.168.1.2", the heredoc is processed on your local machine including the command and variable substitutions. The resulting text is passed as an argument to ssh to be executed on the remote host.
If you want that to be literal text, then quote the heredoc marker:
cat <<'EOF'
# ....^...^
# the rest stays the same


Note you are using a form of the anti-pattern
if (expression)
  return true
else
  return false
end

# expression is already a boolean, just return it
return expression

ssh already exits with a success/failure status, and a function exits the status of the last command executed:
function getversion() {
    backdock="$(cat <<'EOF'
            who
            if vers=$( cat ~/version.txt )
            then
                echo "$vers"
                exit 0
            else
                exit 1
            fi
            logname
EOF
    )"
    ssh -t username@192.168.1.2 "$backdock"
}


Other notes:

We don't even really need a heredoc, plain quoting works as well
function getversion() {
    ssh -t username@192.168.1.2 '
            who
            if vers=$( cat ~/version.txt )
            then
                echo "$vers"
                exit 0
            else
                exit 1
            fi
            logname
    '
}


logname is never executed, one of the exits happens first (it could be I didn't understand your indentation)

capturing the version file is awkward, relying on cat failing. How about
if [[ -f ~/version.txt ]]; then
    cat ~/version.txt
else
    exit 1
fi



